# Creating POCO Classes on Phasis

Tags: entity-framework

I create persistence ignorant classes for an existing DB which is very big and i don't want to create all classes in the beginning i want to create only classes i need and create each class when i need it.
Is there any feature in Entity Framework can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can build incrementally your EDMX file adding only entities you need to use at the moment. Than you need to define only POCO classes defined in your EDMX file or you can use POCO template which will generate POCO classes for you.